# Google+ Count missing from Sharrre

Tags: jquery, css, google-plus, social-media

I setup a [basic Javascript app on IIS7](http://demoportal.esriaustralia.com.au/public/LanguagesOfMelbourne/) about a month back.  I made use of the [Sharrre](http://sharrre.com/) jquery plugin to add some social media buttons to it.

For a couple of months they looked as expected:
**EDIT**
*This below screenshot is not from my site, as I dont have a screengrab from when it was working.  You can kind of see it working from [this image](http://esriaustraliatechblog.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/thecbd.png?w=455&h=286) for proof.*

[image]

However, I have noticed that over the last couple of weeks, it does not appear correctly, regardless of browser and an empty cache:

[image]

I have not made any changes to the code, so looking for some advice to whats causing this?

All I can think of is that perhaps because theres more people sharing it, the number has caused the balloon to somehow move somewhere else or vanish?  I cant see any related errors in Firebug and I do not believe IIS has been fiddled with at the server end.

Comment: What does the code look like?

Comment: I can paste code if we are confident that its CSS related?  App is public BTW.

Comment: No, I don't know that it is CSS related. Wouldn't be my first guess. More likely something changed in the code on Google's end and it's wanting some other feed. A link to a page with the problem would be helpful.

Comment: Its the first link in my Q - http://demoportal.esriaustralia.com.au/public/LanguagesOfMelbourne/

Comment: Ah oops, for some reason I thought that was linking off to something else. Checking it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside your map.js file can you try updating the sharrre initialization code to what's below?

```
$('#shareme').sharrre({
  share: {
    googlePlus: true,
    facebook: true,
    twitter: true,
  },
  buttons: {
    googlePlus: {size: 'tall', annotation:'bubble'},
    facebook: {layout: 'box_count'},
    twitter: {count: 'vertical'},
  },
  enableHover: false,
  enableCounter: false,
  enableTracking: true
});
```

(adding in "annotation:'bubble'" for googlePlus)

Comment: Apologies for not being clearer and causing you confusion.  See edits in Q.

Comment: @Simon Just updated my answer with where I think the problem lies. The change could be something from Google or maybe an update of the Sharrre code? Hard to know, but I think this will fix it for you.

Comment: I just made a slight change a minute or so ago because annotation needed to be singular, not plural. Can you see if your code has that?

Comment: yea, that has fixed it! ThaNKS loads

Answer (score 1):

Add annotation in your configuration:

googlePlus: {size: 'tall', annotation:'bubble'},